# How to flag consecutive shifts in SQL efficiently

Tags: sql

I have a dataset that contains 250,000 rows and is expected to grow at around 100,000 rows a month.

I have data that contains the following columns:

ShiftDate (Day a shift occurred on),

Shift Start Time,

Shift End Time

and Employee Number.

I would like to flag consecutive shifts with a 1 when an Employees Shift End Time  was within 4 hours of the start time of their next shift, otherwise flag it with a 0.
[my data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzpe0.png)

I have tried running a query that joins the table to itself but the run time is too long. I was planning to create the flag based on a case statement using 'NextStart':

```
select shiftdate,
shiftstarttime,
shiftendtime,
EmployeeID,
 (select min(t2.shiftstarttime) from TABLE t2 where t1.EmployeeID=t2.EmployeeID and T2.shiftstarttime > t1.Shiftendtime) as NextStart 
 from 
  TABLE t1
```

I would love to know a more efficient way of trying to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select shiftdate, shiftstarttime, shiftendtime, employeeid,
(Case when  
lead(shiftstarttime, 1) over (partition by employeeid order by shiftdate, shiftstarttime) -  shiftendtime < 4 then 1 else 0 end) as consecutive_shift_flag 
from table_name
```

In this query lead() window function is used to get the next shift start time for that employee

```
lead(shiftstarttime, 1) over (partition by employeeid order by shiftdate, shiftstarttime)
```

In case this is not what you are looking for then please share the Sample of correct output based on input data for couple of cases.